# Emacs is starting in x window version

Tags: linux, emacs

After installing Emacs via `sudo apt-get install Emacs` on a Linux Mint machine, I'm getting to the xwindow version of Emacs every time I start 'Emacs' from the terminal emulator in my window/tile manager.

I'm interested in the command-line version. Did I do something wrong so far?

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the GUI version and install `emacs-nox` it will give you the command line only version.

Alternatively, you could also keep what you have and open it with `emacs -nw`.  The `nw` means "No Window".